# NPOI Word: How to clone row and insert it at the specified index?

Tags: c#, .net, npoi

I have a table in a Word document with 3 rows: 1st for Header, 2nd for Data placeholder, and 3rd for Summary. I want to clone the second row right after it - before Summary row. What I tried to do using NPOI:

`XWPFTableRow.CloneRow()` - it works but adds a new row at the end of the table:

```csharp
XWPFTableRow newRow = dataRow.CloneRow();
```

I looked at the `CloneRow()` source code and tried to repeat the behavior changing `Add()` to `Insert()`. But the new row didn't appear at all:

```csharp
var ctBaseRow = dataRow.GetCTRow();
var newRow = new XWPFTableRow(ctBaseRow.Copy(), table);
table.Rows.Insert(newIndex, newRow);
```

There is also the `InsertNewTableRow()` method that breaks the table:

```csharp
var newRow = table.InsertNewTableRow(newIndex);
```

And `Copy()` method with no effect:

```csharp
XWPFTableRow newRow = dataRow.Copy();
table.Rows.Insert(newIndex, newRow);
```

The question is: How to clone a row and insert it at the specified index?